# Can C# leverage implicit nested generic parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have a quite simple design:

- a generic interface `IElement<>` with a single generic parameter `T`:

  ```
  interface IElement<T>
  {
  }
  ```
- another generic interface `ISource<>` that manages `IElement<>`

In `ISource<>` I have a method that returns the underlying type of `IElement<>`:

```
T GetSomething();
```

Here is what I can do:

```
interface ISource<TElem, T>
    where TElem : IElement<T>
{
    T GetSomething();
}

class IntegersSource : ISource<IElement<int>, int>
{
    public int GetSomething()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But the nested type, here `int`, has to be repeated.

I'd like something like:

```
class IntegersSource : ISource<IElement<int>>
{
    public int GetSomething()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I've tried :

```
interface ISource<TElem>
    where TElem : IElement<T>
{
    T GetSomething();
}
```

But the compiler is not happy with this syntax.

I fear I'm missing something obvious, but what?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what `T` is in your last listing?

Comment: Do you really need `TElem`? Won't `IElement<T>` inside `ISource<>T` implementation be enough for you?

Comment: I don't see any added benefit from the `IElement<T>` interface at all. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: the type is specified when the interface is used.

Comment: @Dennis: yes I really need both, but to be honest having a simpler design is not a game changer, I was just curious. :)

Comment: @Alex: the (minor) benefit is that you don't need to repeat `int` twice (DRY principle). I agree this is not a huge difference. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek: From the point of view of the C# compiler, the identifier `T` is simply not defined at that point. The compiler does not attempt, or not attempt, to deduce a value for the type parameter `T`, it has no idea that `T` is supposed to be a type parameter in the first place.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: yes and I guess this is because .Net generics are not used in a context in which this information can be easily deduced (compile-time) (cf C++) but are compiled to be used at runtime. This limitation makes sense (+ the other oddities spotted by *Heinzi*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work. Image you have the following class:

```
class MultiElement : IElement<int>, IElement<double>
{
    // explicit interface implementations of IElement<int> and IElement<double> here.
}
```

Now when I declare a `class MySource : ISource<MultiElement>`, what should be inferred as `T`?

Comment: You make a really good point, though in my design this would not make any sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly it is not possible. I'd imagine a syntax like this:

```
interface ISource<TElem<T>>
    where TElem : IElement<T>
{
    T GetSomething();
}
```

and the corresponding usage like:

```
class IntegersSource : ISource<IElement<int>>
```

Even though you'd have to explicitly state where the compiler can expect the 'nested' type parameter (see *Heinzi*'s answer for a particular case).

Comment: Yes before posting I've tried this syntax and others without any success. :/

Answer (score 1):

Your desired format:

```
class IntegersSource : ISource<IElement<int>>
{
    public int GetSomething()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

provides the generic parameter to ISource - "TElem" - as `IElement<int>`.

The 'int' part of it is subsequently buried inside the **closed** type defintion. Although *you* can read it, the compiler is unaware of the int in the implementation of IntegersSource.

Comment: I'm pretty sure C++ handles this. I think the issue is that .Net generics are compiled/dynamic and so are less expressive.